# Defining buffer size correct "Stack around the variable String was corrupted"

Tags: c++

I have these two lines in my code:

```
TCHAR String[400] = {0};
SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT,sizeof(String), (LPARAM)String);
```

When I use it that way I sometimes get a runtime error: "Stack around the variable String was corrupted"

When I use

```
TCHAR String[400] = {0};
SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT,10, (LPARAM)String);
```

it works without problems. But I thought that the whole thing about using sizeof() is to make sure that there is no overflow problems.... Why is sizeof(String) not secure and what could I use instead??

Thanks! and have a nice day!

Comment: Why don't you use `GetWindowText` function? And why on Earth are you using that Windows 9x-compatibility scheme? Are you *really* planning on supporting Windows 95 for application that links to MFC DLLs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wchar_t, sizeof(String) will be 800, not 400.  Fix:

```
wchar_t String[400] = 0;
SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(String) / sizeof(wchar_t), (LPARAM)String);
```

Comment: @  Eugen Constantin Dinca: I do not know if its better, I gues both work...  _countof is shorter to type ;-)

Comment: IMO the best solution (short of `std::vector<wchar_t>`) is `const int StringSize = 400; wchar_t String[StringSize] = 0; SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, StringSize, (LPARAM)String);`.